# CakePHP 2.4 CakeEmail: How to access variable set using 'set()' instead of 'viewVars()'

Tags: email, cakephp

I'm upgrading a CakePHP site from 1.3 to 2.4 and the site sends out quite a few emails. In the original version I was using the old Cake Email Component and all the variables that had to be printed out in the email were passed using the controller's `set()` method.

```
// code in controller
$this->set('my_var', 'whatever);
```

In the new version I am using the `CakeEmail` class which is slightly different. One of the differences is that the email's template can no longer 'see' these variables.

```
// code in View/Email template
// works in 1.3 BUT NOT 2.4
echo $my_var;
```

**Question 1:** How do I change my View/Template code to access `$my_var`?

I know I can pass variables to the View/Template using `CakeEmail::setVars()` but I want to avoid this as the structure of my code would make this a bit complicated (lots of nested functions).

Alternatively, how do I get an array of all the variable set using `set()` to pass `viewVars()` just before the email is sent?

```
// How to do this in controller
$my_vars = $this->???? // return array of all vars set so far
$Email->viewVars($my_vars);
$Email->send();
```

Comment: @Thorpe, thanks for the spelling correction.

Comment: The correct code was: `$Email->viewVars(array('my_vars' => $my_vars, 'someother' => $someother));` right before `send()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass data to template using CakeEmail::setVars();
but you can get object variables using this:

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($object));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found I could solve my problem with this line of code:

```
// in controller code
$Email->viewVars($this->viewVars);
```

I'd never come across `Controller::viewVars` before.